# Is constructor() primary constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

These is a primary constructor Code A, right ?

Is constructor() a primary constructor in Code B ?

Is there no a primary constructor in Code B ?

**Code A**

```
class Person constructor(firstName: String) {
}
```

**Code B**

```
class Person {
    var name: String = ""

    constructor()  // Is this a primary constructor

    constructor(name:String):this(){
        this.name = name
    }

}
```

**Code C**

```
class Person {
    var name: String = ""
    constructor(name:String){
        this.name = name
    }

}
```

Comment: See this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin, The primary constructor is part of the class header: it goes after the class name (and optional type parameters).

Read more at [Classes And Inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#classes-and-inheritance) at official documentation.

So, class B does not have primary constructor defined.

Comment: Thanks! Must I  write `constructor(name:String):this(){...}` in Code B ? and `constructor(name:String){...}` in Code C

Comment: @HelloCW No you don't have to. `constructor(name:String) {
        this.name = name
    }` is enough because there is no primary constructor.

Comment: Additional note: in official doc "If the primary constructor does not have any annotations or visibility modifers, the
 constructor keyword can be omitted." So you can't omit "constructor" keyword if you declared any access modifiers or annotations.

Answer (score 4):

The primary constructor is the one described in the header, whether it's just marked by the parentheses after the classname or the explicit `constructor` keyword. What makes the primary constructor special is that its arguments can be used in initializer blocks and property initializers. This is why you *have to* call the primary constructor from every secondary constructor (if the primary constructor exists) - otherwise you could end up with a half-initialized instance of your class. For example:

```
class MyClass(x: String) {
    val length = x.length

    constructor() : this("foo") {
        println("secondary constructor used!")
    }
}
```

If you have a primary constructors, secondary constructors have to *eventually* call the primary one so that proper initialization can take place. This can happen directly or indirectly, even through multiple steps:

```
class MyClass(x: String) {
    val length = x.length

    constructor(x: Int) : this(x.toString()) // calls primary ctor
    constructor(x: Long) : this(x.toInt()) // calls previous secondary ctor with Int param
    constructor(x: Double) : this(x.toLong()) // calls previous secondary ctor with Long param
}
```

And of course two secondary constructors can't call each other:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(x: Int) : this(x.toLong()) // Error: There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain
    constructor(x: Long) : this(x.toInt()) // Error: There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain
}
```

If you don't have a primary constructor at all, your secondary constructors don't have any obligation to call each other. They just have to call the superclass constructor, if there isn't one with no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. No it's not Primary constructor.

> A class in Kotlin can have a primary constructor and one or more
>   secondary constructors. The primary constructor is part of the class
>   header: it goes after the class name (and optional type parameters).

2. Yes, there is no Primary constructor

Answer (score 1):

just code A is primary constructor

code B & C are secondary constructor

**Code A**

```
class Person constructor(firstName: String) { //primary constructor
}
```

**Code B**

```
class Person {
    var name: String = ""

    constructor()  // secondary constructor

    constructor(name:String):this(){  // secondary constructor
        this.name = name
    }

}
```

**Code C**

```
class Person {
    var name: String = ""
    constructor(name:String){// secondary constructor
        this.name = name
    }

}
```

Read more in [KotlinPage](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)